# Adding list item to Thymeleaf field

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the following drop down list for labels that a user can add to a question:

```
  <select th:field="*{label}" id="label" class="form-control">
               <option th:each="label : ${labels}"
                       th:value="${label.labelId}"
                       th:text="${label}"></option>
  </select>
```

Now, I want to add an item in this list to another textfield below the dropdown list whenever a user clicks on an item in the dropdown list. Is this possible without Javascript? Because my JS knowledge is not that great.

In a perfect world, I would just like to recreate the Stackoverflow Tags system, but the answers that I have found here seem a bit complex.

Maybe I wasn't exactly clear, I intend to show the selected labels in the input field below:

```
 <select th:field="*{label}" id="label" class="form-control">
                        <option th:each="label : ${labels}"
                                th:value="${label.labelId}"
                                th:text="${label}"></option>
 </select>

 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="labelSelected" name="labelSelected" placeholder="Selected Labels" />
```

Answer (score 0):

No need Javascript, use Java Enum, for example:

Java code

```
package com.example;

public class AnYear {

    public static enum Season {

        SPRING("spring"),
        SUMMER("summer"),
        AUTUMN("autumn"),
        WINTER("winter");

        private final String season;

        Season(String season) {
            this.season = season;
        }

        public String getSeason() {
            return season;
        }
    }

}
```

Thymeleaf template (*.html file)

```
<select>
    <option th:each="season : ${T(com.example.AnYear.Season).values()}" th:value="${season}" th:text="${season}"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: The labels can be added by a teacher, that's why I'm working with a list. I edited my original post to clarify my question.